# VBA to change links with a workbook, issue excel thinks workbook isn't open

Tags: excel, vba

I have coding to open a previous day workbook then to change source link from original template file to previous day workbook. the coding works but for some reason excel doesn't recognise that the PD WB is open so it therefore won't change the source link (even though it is open) Is there any way this can be resolved?

```
Sub OpenLink()
    Dim strGenericFilePath      As String: strGenericFilePath = "K:\Finance\Unallocated Cash\"
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb1.Sheets("UTM Unal Cash Report")
Dim strYear                 As String: strYear = Year(Date) & "\"
Dim strMonth                As String: strMonth = Format(Date, "mm.Mmmm") & "/"
Dim DateStamp                As String: DateStamp = Format(ws.Range("L2"), "dd.mm.yy")
Dim strFileName             As String: strFileName = ("UTM UT Unallocated" & " " & DateStamp & ".xlsm")
Dim strUAC                  As String: strUAC = "UTM" & "/"
Dim NewTrendlink As String: NewTrendlink = strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strUAC & strFileName
Dim OldTrendlink As String: OldTrendlink = "K:\Finance\Unallocated Cash\2023\09.September\UTM\UTM UT Unallocated 11.09.23.xlsm"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(NewTrendlink, Password:="utm", ReadOnly:=True)
wb1.Activate

    Dim lsArr: lsArr = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    If IsEmpty(lsArr) Then
        MsgBox "No Excel link sources found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
       
    If Len(Dir(NewTrendlink)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & NewTrendlink & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
    Else
        If IsError(Application.Match(OldTrendlink, lsArr, 0)) Then
            MsgBox "This workbook is not linked to """ & OldTrendlink & """.", _
                vbCritical
        Else
            wb.ChangeLink OldTrendlink, NewTrendlink, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
            MsgBox "The workbook is now linked to """ & NewTrendlink & """.", _
                vbInformation
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks

Comment: How do you see Excel isn't recognizing the workbook?

Comment: the error message from the code pops up: 
IsError(Application.Match(OldTrendlink, lsArr, 0)) Then
            MsgBox "This workbook is not linked to """ & OldTrendlink & """.", _
                vbCritical
 but it manages to open the workbook to the new link so just unsure why it can't change the link, if that makes sense because it all looks like it should work

Comment: Can you test with a small for loop through the lsArr and `Debug.Print lsArr(i)` if your link is actually `Dim OldTrendlink As String: OldTrendlink = "K:\Finance\Unallocated Cash\2023\09.September\UTM\UTM UT Unallocated 11.09.23.xlsm"`? It only takes one character different for your error to be thrown.

Comment: thank you for this,  i did that and found the error! you were right it turned out to be one character causing the error

Comment: Glad to have helped :)